# Captain America suit's raised surface pattern?

Tags: sewing, fabric, material-identification, costume-design

What is the technique/fabric technology to make raised surface pattern as seen on Captain America suits (see the image below)? At first sight, I thought it was quilting pattern, but upon closer inspection, I noticed that there is no stitching line at all around the bumpy pattern! It is so fascinating!
[image]

Comment: The key word here is "embossing". If you look online for "emboss fabric" you'll find a lot of options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this and still keep the material flexible.  Here are a couple that lend themselves to low-quantity, low-cost applications:

- Start with a sandwich of foam rubber, like EVA, between two layers of fabric.  The outer layer of fabric needs to be a little stretchy, and the backing fabric non-stretch.  Use spray adhesive to bond the layers together.  Use a heatable metal template in a press to create the pattern.
- Use a vacuum table to suck the fabric (should be a little stretchy), into a template of the pattern.  Apply a coating to the back of a material that bonds with the fabric but is thick enough to not soak through it, and dries rubbery, like silicone caulk.
- Like the previous method, suck the fabric into a pattern template on a vacuum table.  Insert pre-cut patterns of foam, like EVA, into the cavities.  Apply fabric glue to the ridges of the pattern and bond a non-stretch backing fabric.

There are also a few other ways:

- For large quantity runs and complex designs, you can invest in creating mating metal dies (expensive).  The fabric is coated on the back with a material like silicone and then pressed in the dies to emboss it, typically with a hydraulic press.
- It's possible to get the appearance of deep embossing by silk screening with puff ink.  If the color is matched to the fabric and a fuzzy fabric is used, the ink can look like the fabric.  But I'm not aware that you can give the ink a surface texture.  So this would not be a way to replicate something like the Captain America suit, where the fabric texture is very visible.